# Rotating molecule representations with rdkit

Tags: cheminformatics

I'm trying to display some molecules in rdkit and save them as png files. Simple enough. However, when I display them, most of them are drawn at a weird angle (shown below) or even completely upside down. I tried using [this](http://www.rdkit.org/docs/GettingStartedInPython.html#drawing-molecules) section to correct this but no luck. I've looked through similar issues people had but none of them have been properly resolved as far as I can tell.

[image]

Does anybody have a solution to this?

Thank you !

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can use `SetPreferCoordGen(True)`

```python
from rdkit import Chem
from rdkit.Chem import rdDepictor
rdDepictor.SetPreferCoordGen(True)

mol = Chem.MolFromSmiles('Fc1ccc2ncccc2c1')
mol
```

[image: Mol]